# If $g(a)$ is discontinuous at $x=a$ and $f(a)$ is continuous at $x=a$, what can we say about $g(x)f(x)$ at $x=a$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $g(a)$ is discontinuous at $x=a$ and $f(a)$ is continuous at $x=a$, what can we say about continuity of $g(x)f(x)$ at $x=a$?

Many of the examples I have seen are about continuity are over an entire domain instead of a specific point and the most common counterexample I have seen is to set $f(x)=0$ over the domain, then $f(x)g(x)$ will always be continuous since it is just the constant function $0$.

However, if we are only talking about continuity at a specific point, $f(a)= 0$ would not be enough for us to conclude that $f(a)g(a)$ is continuous at $x=a$ since any points in the neighborhood of a can be mapped to values other than $0$ by $f(x)$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(a) \neq 0$ the $f(x)g(x)$ cannot be continuous at $a$ since $g(x)=\frac  1{f(x)} {f(x)g(x)}\to g(a)$).

If $f(a)=0$ then $f(x)g(x)$  may or may not be continuous at $a$

Examples: Let  $g(x)=\frac  1 x$ for $x \neq 0, g(0)=0$. Let $a=0$ Consider the cases $f(x)=\sqrt {|x|}$ and $f(x)=x^{2}$

Comment: For the case $f(a)=0$, I think we can add that if $g$ is bounded, then $f(x)g(x)$ is continuous in $a$.

Comment: @zwim Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is as you expect. For example, for $a=0$, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and $g(x)=1/x^2$ for $x>0$ we have that $f$ is continuous and $f(0)=0$, but $g(x)f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and $g(x)f(x)=1/x$ for $x>0$ is not continuous in $0$.